# Can i do submodeling technique for an ODB file of abaqus?

Tags: scripting, abaqus, odb

i have an ODB file, i want to get result of some elements of the model. is it possible to do submodeling on ODB? If so, can I get abaqus script to do?

Comment: Do you want to export results of some elements to a file or do you really want an Odb, which contains only a part of the whole model?

Comment: Are we talking about ODB the C++ database library or ODB the file format for electrical layouts?